# how to sort Arraylist of string having integer values in java

Tags: java, android

I am having string list which consists of integer values. i just want to sort in ascending as well as in descending order.

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("1435536000000");
a.add("1435622400000");

System.out.println("Before : " + a);
Collections.sort(a, new ComparatorOfNumericString());
System.out.println("After : " + a);
```

My  ComparatorOfNumericString class is -

```
public class ComparatorOfNumericString implements Comparator<String> {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(lhs);
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(rhs);
        return Integer.compare(i1, i2);
    }

}
```

Any one having idea how to sort this strings having integer values in java?

Thanks a lot!! in Advance!!

Comment: do your homework by yourself

Comment: Use collection class for sorting

Comment: Why don't you add these strings by converting as `Integer` in `ArrayList`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort strings that contain numbers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529045/how-do-i-sort-strings-that-contain-numbers-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting string array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546396/sorting-string-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The better way will be to add integers/long in to the ArrayList and then sorting it using `Collections.sort(a)` method.

If you still want to using String, you will need to make some modifications. Please find below code for the same:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Input implements Comparator<String>{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add("1435536000000");
        a.add("1435622400000");
        a.add("1");
        a.add("10");
        a.add("20");
        a.add("15");
        a.add("1435622400010");

        System.out.println("Before : " + a);
        Collections.sort(a, new Input());
        System.out.println("After : " + a);
          }

    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
    long i1 = Long.parseLong(lhs);
    long i2 = Long.parseLong(rhs);
    return (int) (i1-i2);
   }

}
```

Comment: @ All- all i need to do is- I have time stamp which consists of long value. I just need to sort this time stamp so that i can see nearest date 1st and longest date belo..like 1435622400000- is Tue, 30 Jun 2015 and 1435536000000 is-Mon, 29 Jun 2015  i want to sort in sch a way that i can see 1st 29 Jun 2015 then 30 Jun 2015

Comment: The above example will help you to solve this. If you want to sort in a reverse direction just do (i2-i1) in compare method.

Comment: no its not working for me. but thnx for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
Collections.sort(a);
```

Without any Comparator. It will sort any `String` alphabetically so logically it will serve for `integer` String too.

Comment: this case "101" will be larger than "1001", so this sort will be wrong

Comment: @VladMatvienko did you solve this issue you mentioned?

Comment: @TusharGogna, sure, you just need a custom comparator as a second argument. In it you need to convert values to numbers before comparing them. This way it will compare as expected

Comment: @TusharGogna, see `abhijeet dhumal` answer. It is exactly what I ment

Comment: I'm comparing alphanumeric. It is working fine except this bug you mentioned. eg: ABC 3999 is shown smaller than ABC 999. Also, it is not handling upper-lower case. :/

Answer (score -1):

You can use this methods to sorting the Strings.

```
Collections.sort(arraylist);// for ascending order
Collections.sort(arraylist, Collections.reverseOrder());// for descending order.
```